# How can I access instantiated from another class?

Tags: angular, typescript, object

Recently I faced this problem where I cant seem to find a way to pass a instantiated object to another class.

I need to pass the instantiated object userModel from **main.page.ts** to **menu.page.ts**

I seems like there is very little info about this. I found one question quite similar to mine but It didnt fixed the problem.

**main.page.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { User } from 'src/app/user';
import { EnrollmentService } from '../../../Services/enrollment.service';
import {Md5} from 'ts-md5/dist/md5';

@Component({
   selector: 'app-main',
   templateUrl: './main.page.html',
   styleUrls: ['./main.page.scss'],
})
export class MainPage implements OnInit {

SERVER_URL = 'http://ruben-pc/form/76/2';
submitted = false;
userModel = new User('CT', 'testeteste', false);
md5 = new Md5();



constructor(public httpClient: HttpClient, private enrollmentService: EnrollmentService) {
}

ngOnInit() {

}
}
```

**menu.page.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { User } from '../../user';

@Component({
selector: 'app-menu',
templateUrl: './menu.page.html',
styleUrls: ['./menu.page.scss'],
})
export class MenuPage {

pages = [
 {
   title: 'Login',
  url: '/menu/main',
  icon: 'home'
},
{
  title: 'Funcionalidades',
  children: [
    {
      title: 'Listagem Questionário',
      url: '/menu/flutter',
      icon: 'ios-clipboard'
    },
  ]
}
];

constructor() { 
  console.log(this.userModel.loggedIn);
}
}
```

Comment: Is main.page.ts and menu.page.ts have parent child relation? if yes then you can use `input` `output` for the same if no then you can use `RxJS` `behaviourSubject`

Comment: If you want more detailed answer provide your project structure on https://stackblitz.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you have two components that live on different routes you probably should use dependency injection for creating this `userModel` something like:

```
@NgModule({
  ...
  providers: {
    ...
    {
      provide: User, // needs to be decorated with @Injectable
      useValue: User('CT', 'testeteste', false),
    }
  }
})
class SomeModule {}
```

and in your components

```
  constructor(
    ...
    user: User, // then it will be available under this.user
  )
```

Also there is a lot of documentation just read [Angular documentation](https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection)

Comment: where should I put the @NgModule part?

Comment: @RuiGuerreiro you probably should have at least AppModule you can add it there and if you want to know more [modules documentation](https://angular.io/guide/ngmodules)